# DotNetNuke: GridView incompatible with Data Access Layer?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, dotnetnuke, web-controls

I'm working on a DotNetNuke module in C#, and in order to cut down on the amount of complexity I have elected to try and keep the configuration of the module in one page (other than the standard Settings module).  I now wonder how wise of an idea that is.

My module is a simple image gallery, with one or many images.  Each image has a title, an image source (url) and a destination (another url).  Therefore, I figured that for my admin interface, I could have a simple 'grid' of data where you can edit all of the existing entries or add a new one, all on the same page, sort of like this:

```
 Title              Image URL                           Anchor HREF
[A Picture!      ] [http://www.example.com/image.jpg ] [http://www.example.com]
[Another Picture!] [http://www.example.com/image2.jpg] [http://www.example.net]
[                ] [                                 ] [                      ]
```

Looking through WebControls, I found the GridView, which at first blush seemed like the sort of thing I was looking for.  However, taking a closer gander at it, I found that it needed to be bound directly to a data source, while it seems like the DotNetNuke standard of doing things in the Data Access Layer is to create a collection of data objects like so:

```
// EditDiscovery.ascx.cs
DiscoveryController objDiscoverys = new DiscoveryController();
List<DiscoveryInfo> lstDiscoveries = objDiscoverys.GetDiscoverys(ModuleId);

// DiscoveryController.cs
public List<DiscoveryInfo> GetDiscoverys(int ModuleId) {
    return CBO.FillCollection<DiscoveryInfo>(DataProvider.Instance().GetDiscoverys(ModuleId));
}
```

Is there something I'm missing with the GridView, or should I be changing the GetDiscoverys function to return a DataSet as opposed to a List of DiscoveryInfo objects?  Or is there a better approach that does things that align better with DotNetNuke's DAL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to set the list of `DiscoveryInfo` objects to the grid.

```
MyGrid.DataSource = lstDiscoveries;
MyGrid.DataBind();
```

Comment: Ah, from what I was reading I was under the impression that I had to supply a DataSet or something "closer to the metal". In retrospect, it was a simple solution, but these things aren't quite obvious to someone who is just starting out with C# and ASP.NET, and my initial response to your rseponse was "Oh, I didn't know DataSource could take a list of objects".  Thanks!